# Listener event not firing after building through sencha

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, sencha-touch

I have build my project through command line in sencha but after the build the listener event for a particular controller didnt work. The alert that I included in the listener didnt get called. My main issue was that the localStorage.providerName after the label "Tell your friends about" sometimes prints undefined so tried to implement in listener, but the function in listener is not getting called. Any suggestions? Below is the part of code where the event listener doesnt get called.

```
Ext.define('Myl.view.ShareView', {
                              extend: Ext.Panel,
                              id:'shareView',
                              xtype :'shareView',
                              alias: 'widget.shareView',
                              config: {
                              cls:'mainBackground',
                              items: [
                                      {
                                      xtype:'toptoolbar',
                                      docked:'top'
                                      },
                                      {
                                      xtype: 'label',
                                      id: 'tellAFriendTopLabel',
                                      //                 html: 'Tell your friends about '+localStorage.providerName,
                                      padding: 5
                                      },
                                      {
                                      xtype: 'button',
                                      margin: 20,
                                      text: 'Facebook',
                                      ui:'facebook_button',
                                      iconCls:'facebookIconCls',
                                      action : 'facebookButtonPressed'
                                      },
                                      {
                                      xtype: 'button',
                                      margin: 20,
                                      text: 'Twitter',
                                      iconCls:'twitterIconCls',
                                      ui:'twitter_button',
                                      action : 'twitterButtonPressed'
                                      },
                                      {
                                      xtype: 'button',
                                      margin: 20,
                                      text: 'Email',
                                      ui:'email_button',
                                      iconCls:'emailIconCls',
                                      action : 'emailButtonPressed'
                                      },
                                      {

                                      xtype :'footerPanel',
                                      docked:'bottom'
                                      }
                                      ]
                              },
                              listeners: {
                              painted: function (element, options) {
                              alert('test1');
                              Ext.getCmp('tellAFriendTopLabel').setHtml('Tell your friends about '+localStorage.providerName+'.');
                              this.fireEvent('initiateShareView');

                              }

                              }
                              });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put your listeners inside config object.

However, I wouldn't recommend this approach because if somebody wants to listen painted event, the new handler will override yours. I'd suggest to do it using 'on' method in 'initialize'.

Take a look at the initialize method of this component: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/source/List.html#Ext-dataview-List